# Cannot install Elementary Tweaks in Loki (no release file for the repo)

Tags: release-loki, apt, repositories, tweak-tool

I'm back to elementary after some absence and I hope to keep using it, but I have no big incentive so far.

After discovering that adding repos was disabled by default, as well as the Ubuntu's *Software and Updates* interface, and after repairing that with `sudo apt install software-properties-common software-properties-gtk`
, I have [this problem](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/15284/170) (all sources lack release file), which also entails I guess the fact that the repo I have added for Elementary Tweaks (`ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks`) is also affected.

```
cipeos@cipeos:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki InRelease                                                                        
Hit:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                               
Hit:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                                           
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki InRelease                                                                  
Ign:6 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter loki InRelease                                  
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                  
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Err:9 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter loki Release                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.4.44 80]
Hit:10 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                   
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki Release     
  404  Not Found
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki Release
  404  Not Found
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done                                                
E: The repository 'http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
cipeos@cipeos:~$ sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package elementary-tweaks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar to [my other question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/15284/170) and can be solved in a similar way, but I am not sure it is the same bug (and therefore a duplicate just like that one) or caused by the added repo which writes **bionic** instead of **xenial** in the file it creates `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/philip_scott-ubuntu-elementary-tweaks-bionic.list`.

So:

Right click on the Files icon in Plank dock, select New Window As Administrator, go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder and edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/philip_scott-ubuntu-elementary-tweaks-bionic.list` by replacing **bionic** with **xenial**.